# Error during Apache Installation

Tags: apache

I am just integration all the three as mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/748117/how-to-manually-install-apache-php-and-mysql-on-windows)

While installing apache,

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

is added in `httpd.conf` It says

```
(OS 10013)An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its  
access permissions.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 
127.0.0.1:80
AH00451: no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

I just checked what process is using port 80

```
 netstat -tna
```

shows `pid 4 is using`

When i check

```
 tasklist
```

it says `SYSTEM` process is using.

How do i make use of system port 80 for apache? How do i resolve this error?

Comment: Either it's your skype or MS IIS server might be using port 80.

Comment: Hi Swain , thanks. Yes, IIS is using? Should i stop that? please let me know how did you find this?

Comment: So now whether you are dependent on IIS fro any work or not? If not then let me know i will tell u how to stop IIS.

Comment: No, I don't use this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a CMD prompt (as Admin) and type this iisreset /stop
[image]