# How do I specify a port in url?

Tags: php, apache

I got stuck with [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29058266/error-during-apache-installation)

For a temporary solution, I changed the port to `5555` in `apache httptd.conf`

```
 localhost
```

shows `default index.html content`

I integerated `php` with `apache` and then started `apache` by executing `httpd.exe`

```
localhost:5555/index.php
```

says `url error` How do i achieve this?